# Java method run only once the full code after a scheduler runnable shutdown using JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Im stuck programing a Tetris game trying to learn Java and JavaFX.
When I call the method the first time from method start it runs well, when I call it from the thread it only runs partially, and dont add a new node to the pane.

[Here](https://github.com/free4GOD/tetris/blob/master/src/tetris/Tetris.java) is part of the code, you can view it entirely in

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ...
    stage.show();
    newPieces();
}

public void newPieces() {
    Pieces pieces = new Pieces();
    piece = pieces.createPiece();
    nextPiece = pieces.createPiece();
    boolean add1 = vbox.getChildren().add(nextPiece);
    boolean add2 = pane.getChildren().add(piece);
    translateDown(piece);
}

public void translateDown(Group piece) {
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean translate = piece.getTransforms().add(new Translate(0, 25));
            ...
            ...
            newPieces();
            scheduler.shutdown();
            ...
            ...
       }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The method newPieces creates a Group of Rectangles.

Thanks!

Comment: What I'm trying to do with this code is to generate a new block of the tetris and translate it until bottom of pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a executor to schedule the updates I recommend using a `Timeline` which executes a frame's event handler on the application thread. Running the updates on a application thread is important since modifying properies of nodes on a different thread is problematic:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> {
    updateBoard(); // do things like moving a piece...

    if (checkLoss()) {
        // stop updates when game is lost
        timeline.stop();
    }
}));

// repeat indefinitely
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

timeline.play();
```

You could also use `timeline.pause()` to pause the game and set the `rate` property to speed up the game...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the javafx gui components you have to run the code on the javafx thread. The extra thread you start is not allowed to access the javafx elements. The exception thrown is probably uncatched.

Try `Platform.runLater(Runnable runnable)` with the code modifing the gui. This runs the specified runnable on the javafx thread at some time in the future.